# SQL: MTD Calculation on specific dates

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to Calculate MTD sales on daily sales number but my month starts from 26th of previous month to 25th of next month.

data contains only 3 columns (date, vendor_id, total_sales).
Below Code is working fine for calculating months starting from the 1st. I tried to do this by using the below approaches but it does not works

1. date(date - interval '25 day') : Not working
2. Mapping table creation for each day, but will not work for 30/31 days month

Need suggestion on above.

```
SUM(sales) OVER (
            PARTITION BY 
                vendor_id, 
                EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date), 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) 
            ORDER BY 
                date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        ) AS mtd_total_sales,
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected output? It's not clear how do you want to show the data finally.

Comment: @James: Added screenshot for data

Answer (score 2):

So, if the date is >= 26, then "it is the next month".

As a result, something like

```
CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM date) >= 26 THEN ADD_MONTHS(date, 1)
    ELSE date
END
```

should suffice, since you extract the year and month anyway.